# Delegates and protocols with VC not connected

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have a parent view controller i.e. HomeViewController which has a navigation bar button via which a user can trigger an alert and enter a string. This string needs to be passed to the child view controller.

Here is the relevant code in the parent view controller:

```
protocol NewSectionDelegate {
    func sendSectionName(name : String)
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
var sectionNameDelegate : NewSectionDelegate?

func addCardAsChild() { // add the child VC to the parent VC
if cardViewController == nil {
                cardViewController = CardViewController()
                addViewController(newViewController: cardViewController!)
            } else {
                addViewController(newViewController: cardViewController!)
            }
}

func triggerAlert() {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New section", message: "Name the section with a words or a sentence", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler:
                    {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in //txtview customization
                    })

                let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
                    guard let sectionName = alertController.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
                    self.sectionNameDelegate?.sendSectionName(name: sectionName) // Sending string; verified that the string is not nil
                }

                alertController.addAction(addAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here is the child view controller:

```
class CardViewController: UIViewController,  NewSectionDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
        homeViewController.sectionNameDelegate = self
     }

    func sendSectionName(name: String) {
print("received name:\(name)") // This line of code is never called
}
```

The data is not getting passed and I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you using storyboard? If yes `HomeViewController()` is not the instance you expect.

Comment: No. It's all programmatic.

Comment: Nevertheless you are creating the instance of `HomeViewController`, then the delegate is set and the instance is thrown away.

Comment: Then the questions is where would I place the code? I tried viewDidAppear but that's not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
protocol NewSectionDelegate {
    func sendSectionName(name : String)
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var sectionNameDelegate : NewSectionDelegate?
    var cardViewController = CardViewController()

    func addCardAsChild() { // add the child VC to the parent VC
        self.addChild(self.cardViewController)
    }

    func triggerAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New section", message: "Name the section with a words or a sentence", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler:
            {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in //txtview customization
        })

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
            guard let sectionName = alertController.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
            self.sectionNameDelegate?.sendSectionName(name: sectionName) // Sending string; verified that the string is not nil
        }

        alertController.addAction(addAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class CardViewController: UIViewController,  NewSectionDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let homeViewController = self.parent as? HomeViewController else { return }
        homeViewController.sectionNameDelegate = self
    }

    func sendSectionName(name: String) {
        print("received name:\(name)") // This line of code is never called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the delegate method is getting called but for the internal `HomeViewController` you're making in the `ChildViewController` `viewDidLoad` method.  It looks like you're expecting the method to get called on a different object.  I would remove that code from `viewDidLoad` and set the `sectionNameDelegate` in `HomeViewController`

Comment: It is always helpful to use the code provided by the poster, optimize it and proof for yourself that it works. Then you can tell the requester how he or she can solve his problem.